# Topology of diffeomorphism groups which preserve the volume element.

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, differential-topology

Let $M$ be a manifold.

In the Example1.3. of *Topological Methods in Hydrodynamics* (V.I.Arnold, B.A. Khesin), it is written that diffeomorphisms preserving the volume element in a domain $M$ form a Lie group.

How is this topology defined? It is not explained before Example1.3..

**Added**

Now I understand how to define the Whitney topology for this group $\text{SDiff}(M)$.
 However, are $\text{SDiff}(M)$ and $\text{Diff}$(M) differentiable manifold?

Comment: It forms an infinite-dimensional Lie group (not a finite-dimensional one like you're probably more used to!). The topology is the subspace topology of $\text{Diff}(M)$.

Comment: What is the topology of $\text{Diff}(M)?$

Answer (score 1):

You take the Whitney $C^\infty$-topology. A basis of this is given by 
$$S^k(U) = \{ f \in C^{\infty}(M,M) : (J^kf)(M) \subseteq U \}$$
where $k$ runs over all integers and $U$ over all open subsets of $$J^k(M,M).$$The latter is the space of $k$-jets of smooth maps $f \in C^{\infty}(M,M)$, its topology is defined in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jet_(mathematics)#Jets_of_functions_from_a_manifold_to_a_manifold